# How to access .env variable based on the mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, dotenv

Let's say I have 2 files which are `.env.development` and `.env.production`.

In my `package.json`, since the mode is development, it should access `.env.development` for the variables.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js"
```

webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const Dotenv = require("dotenv-webpack");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/index.jsx"),
  devtool: "source-map",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "/dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    static: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    open: true,
  },
  resolve: {...},
  module: {...},
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "public/index.html",
      filename: "index.html",
      favicon: "public/favicon.ico",
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: "process/browser",
    }),
  ],
};
```

So that in the frontend, when I use `process.env`, it will access the variable in `.env.development`.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the system environment variable `NODE_ENV` at the beginning of the npm script. Use this environment variable to control the built environment.

E.g.

`package.json`:

```json
"scripts": {
  "build:dev": "webpack",
  "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack",
  "dev": "webpack serve"
}
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require("path");
const Dotenv = require("dotenv-webpack");

const mode =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "production" : "development";

console.log("mode: ", mode);

module.exports = {
  mode,
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/index.jsx"),
  devtool: "source-map",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "./dist"),
    clean: true,
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    static: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    open: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv({
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, `./.env.${mode}`),
    }),
  ],
};
```

`.env.development`:

```
PWD=123456
```

`.env.production`:

```
PWD=a)d4125z
```

For development build `npm run build:dev`, the output of `./dist/main.js`:

```js
/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
var __webpack_exports__ = {};
/*!***********************!*\
  !*** ./src/index.jsx ***!
  \***********************/
console.log("PWD: ", "123456");

/******/ })()
;
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```

For production build `npm run build`,  the output:

```js
console.log("PWD: ","a)d4125z");
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```